Can a government shift toward a different policy/campaign/program?
Here is my original sentence:

By shifting towards vocational education, these countries can orient young adults into the right paths that are more likely to give them job stability in the future.

I initially thought using shifting towards this way was fine, but then it occurred to me that it is seemingly a policy that shifts toward another, not the government or country. Is that logic correct? If it is, could you suggest something else? I'm considering transitioning to.

It could shift focus, shift funding, etc.

Shift, transition,  both fine.  It's your choice.

You're right to question your choice there.  shifting towards is a casual, imprecise, "broad brush" way of describing the situation,  perhaps best used only in a summation after you have provided particulars in the body of the essay.  Your transitioning to is no better or worse.  BTW, usually one would say something about  shifting away from one thing and towards another.

This is a kind of metonymy -- the government is being equated with its policies. Policies don't have agency, governments do.'

Since governments contain the active participants in politics, we often use them as the subjects of sentences when talking about their policies. In this case, the government is shifting its policies. We can either anthropomorphize the policies and say that the policies shift, or we can say that the government is shifting.
